# Broken layout with firefox 20

Tags: bug, firefox

Is it just me, or did the layout on the questions page break with Firefox 20 for other people too? And if so, is it Firefox's fault?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found out what triggered it: Selecting a bigger font size. I have View → Zoom → Zoom text only enabled, and when I zoom in, the font size increases while other sizes stay the same, and then the layout breaks, as the “ASK QUESTION” item floats to the line below.

I think this is most likely a CSS bug on the site, and not Firefox's fault.

Comment: It seems that similar problems [have been discussed](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Zoom+text+only%22+site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com) at meta.SO; in particular [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20697/few-font-size-related-layout-issues) seems to be relevant. (Notice the status-declined tag there.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for the links. Indeed, it looks like they are not going to want to fix it. Now I stumbled upon it by accident; I had accidentally zoomed in more than intended, so for me, personally, this does not have high priority. But for people with poor eyesight it could easily become an issue. For them, zooming the entire page to the point where they can read the text could easily make the page not fit on the screen anymore. So zoom text only becomes the only useful method.